# Upgrading Matplotlib from 1.4.3 to 1.5.0 kills scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a real-time scatter plot using Matplotlib.  I initially create the scatter plot empty like this:

```
pv.sc = axis.scatter([],[],c=[],s=10, lw=0,cmap=cm)
```

Each second as the data to be plotted is updated, I use set_offsets and set_facecolor to update the values I'm plotting as follows:

```
scalar_value = array(pv.Data[0][1])
scalar_time = array(pv.Data[0][0])
lat,lon,alt = self.InterpGPS(scalar_time)
c_mean = mean(scalar_value)
stdev = std(scalar_value)
pv.sc.set_offsets(zip(lon,lat))
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin = c_mean, vmax = c_mean+2*stdev, clip = False)
m = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm)
pv.sc.set_facecolor(m.to_rgba(scalar_value))
pv.sc.set_clim(vmin = c_mean, vmax = c_mean+2*stdev)
```

Under Matplotlib 1.4.3, this works perfectly but upon upgrading to 1.5.0, the color plot vanishes.  No errors are generated, just no color.  I looked in the version notes for Matplotlib and couldn't see anything obvious that had changed, but wondered if anyone else has encountered similar behavior?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The following works perfectly for me using matplotlib 1.5.0:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print(plt.matplotlib.__version__)
# 1.5.0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

sc = ax.scatter([], [], c=[], cmap='coolwarm', vmin=0, vmax=1, s=60)

sc.set_offsets(np.random.rand(2, 100))
sc.set_array(np.random.rand(100))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Perhaps the problem is that your axis limits don't encompass the data points? Setting the scatter offsets manually will not automatically rescale the axes.

It's difficult to guess what the problem might be without having access to the rest of your code and your input data.